# UIImage causing my app to crash: Received memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios7

Since I upgraded my device to iOS7 I get many warnings

```
2013-10-29 15:20:16.592 App Name[3820:60b] Received memory warning.
2013-10-29 15:20:16.695 App Name[3820:60b] Received memory warning.
2013-10-29 15:20:22.711 App Name[3820:60b] Received memory warning.
```

Then my app crashes

> Terminated due to Memory Pressure

It seems like it is the background Image that is causing the error:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
     //This will cause problems if I uncomment
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    //                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
  }
```

The strange part is it does not happen on the simulator, only on the device.

Comment: How big is the image? Is this specific to your upgrade to iOS 7?

Comment: @Wain I made a new background with High resolution, so it can be used in my iPad app also.

Comment: So you're loading an @2x iPad background on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading large images on smaller / older devices isn't going to go well. You should name your images for the device / resolution that you are making the app available on and load the appropriate image at runtime. iOS will take care of the resolution for you (if you follow the naming standard) but for general images you will need to take care of the platform part yourself. To do this, use a combination of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` and `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`.

For example (at the most basic level without differentiating between iPhone screen sizes):

```
background_iPhone.png
background_iPhone@2x.png
background_iPad.png
background_iPad@2x.png
```

Also, if you can use a tile as the background for the app, do that. It's the most efficient way to specify the image and the SDK will tile it for you.

Comment: Ok this makes sense but how should I named them, could you add an example, also I don't understand the tile/background suggestion, do you mind adding code example?

Comment: If you're using a full size image you should really add an image view behind your other views instead of using a pattern colour.

Comment: Thanks, it's a background image, how would you do it?, it should take the whole screen

Comment: Depends on the structure of your app and which screens it should be shown on. An image view on the nav controller view and each view pushed in with a transparent background maybe...

Comment: yes I realized that colorWithPattern is using a lot of memory, I would like to use your advice, my app is embedded in a navigation controller but I am not able to drag& drop an imageView on it.